# Tomcat do not redeploy modified JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

Though I'm not much experience in it, but have seen many times that modified JSP sometimes don't get change while refreshing the page. I have to manually delete the source and .class of JSP from \work\Catalina\localhost..., only after that I get change. WHY??

Comment: Can you confirm the version of Tomcat you're using? And whether you've made any notable amendments to the server configuration files (in ${TOMCAT_HOME}/conf)

Comment: Currently I'm using Tomcat 6.0.29, and I haven't made any changes in configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times when I have made changes to JSPs and it doesn't show up there was a syntax error with the JSP.  Check your tomcat log to see if there was an exception while compiling the JSP.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on settings, Tomcat should be able to auto reload JSPs when you reinstall the war file. That being said, the behavior has always been extremely flakey for for me. What I tend to do is create a Makefile (even if using ant or maven for builds) to install new copies of the war file: Effectively, it:

1. If `work` directory exists in `${tomcat}`, delete it
2. If `${webapp}` directory exists in `${tomcat}/webapps`, delete it
3. Copy `${dev}/target/${webapp}.war` to `${tomcat}/webapps`